# changing the frame type without loosing data

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using Opencv and I have two frame : cv::frame1 and cv::frame2, when I check their type I get :

```
 frame1.type()  is 16 
frame2.type() is 21
```

my Question is how can I change the type of frame2 to 16 without losing its data ??  I tried frame2.convertTo() it didn't work .

any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to convert an image of type CV_32FC3 (3 channel float) to CV_8UC3 (3 channel unsigned char). This cannot be done without losing some information: In the first case you have 4 bytes per pixel and in the second 1 byte per pixel, so as you understand there is going to be some loss.

This code is used to convert to a different type and works fine for me:

```
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_32FC3, CV_RGB(1.0,1.0,1.0));
cv::Mat B;
A.convertTo(B, CV_8UC3);
```

Comment: I agree that I have to lose some data but my problem is that I lose evrything

Comment: @Engine What do you mean by "everything"?

Comment: all my data  get lost a frame full with 0

Comment: @Engine See new edit. If this doesn't work for you, you have to provide the relevant code (where you declare and initialize your matrices and how you call `convertTo()` otherwise I cannot just guess what is going wrong). Also, do you check the values after and they are all 0 or you just show the image and it's all black? (If the case is the second, you should multiply by 255 so you can see the image.)